# global name 'K_ENTER' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x, pygame

Ese error me sale cuando intento presionar el enter o incluso cuando quiero presionar el espacio me sale el mismo error...

```
def Menu():
   #Llama a la variable global dificultad
   global dificultad
   #Carga y guarda la imagen de la carpeta dibujo
   Nombre_Full = os.path.join('dibujo', 'Fondo_Menu4.png')
   #Carga la imagen y la asigna a la variable Menug
   Menug=pygame.image.load(Nombre_Full)
   #Muestra en pantalla la imagen guardada en Ganag
   screen.blit(Menug,(0,0))
   #Ciclo infinito que terminara cuando el usuario aprete un boton
   while dificultad == 0:
       for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
             if event.key==K_SPACE:
                 dificultad =1
             if event.key==K_ENTER: 
                 dificultad = 2
       pygame.display.flip()
       pygame.time.delay(50)
```

Comment: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html

Answer (score 1):

Nunca he usado Python, pero una búsqueda de 2 minutos me lleva a la documentación de pygame, con una lista de los identificadores usados para distinguir las letras del teclado: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html

Mirando la lista, queda claro que no existe un identificador `K_ENTER` (que es lo que dice el mensaje de error) pero sí un identificador `K_RETURN`.

Además, como no pones el `pygame.` delante busca el símbolo como símbolo local, y no como símbolo de `pygame`.

Solución:

```
if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
   dificultad =1
if event.key== pygame.K_RETURN: 
   dificultad = 2
```